# [byte-buddy]Why only last interceptor works

Tags: byte-buddy

There is a method `testFoo`in my code which looks like this:

```
newClassBuilder = newClassBuilder.method(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith("test"))
                                .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(new InstMethodsInter(new MethodInterceptor1())));
newClassBuilder = newClassBuilder.method(ElementMatchers.named("testFoo"))
                                .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(new InstMethodsInter(new MethodInterceptor2())));
newClassBuilder = newClassBuilder.method(ElementMatchers.nameEndsWith("Foo"))
                               .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(new InstMethodsInter(new MethodInterceptor3())));
```

only MethodInterceptor3 works.
I have lots of interceptors. 
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a most-specific matcher yourself and specify the interceptors yourself there:

```
newClassBuilder.method(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith("test").and(ElementMatchers.named("testFoo"))
                            .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(new InstMethodsInter(new MethodInterceptor1()).andThen(MethodDelegation.to(InstMethodsInter(new MethodInterceptor2()))));
```

This is necessary as the later matcher override any previous matcher that also matches a method. The most specific matcher needs to be applied last and interceptors are not stacked.

However, it seems like you should refactor your interception logic here to make this unnecessary.